# Parellel execution using Karate framework

Tags: java, karate, cucumber-jvm

Currently I am using parallels execution feature of karate framework.
Using Runner class as following.

```
public static Results parallel(String tagSelector, List<Resource> resources, int threadCount, String reportDir) {
    return parallel(tagSelector, resources, null, null, threadCount, reportDir);
}
```

In order to understand ,is the feature files parsed in resources list will be run in seperate thread or each scenario wise seperation is possible ?

Comment: please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallelfalse